# how to get python infinity with good properties

Tags: python, infinite, infinity

For a project I am currently working on, I need to multiply matrices with possibly infinite values in them.

The problem is that every infinite value I found on python is such that `inf * 0 = NaN`, so when you multiply by a matrix with infinities in it, you get a vector with only `inf` an `NaN`. So I need a infinite such that `0 * inf = 0`

I've found `sys.float_info.max`, but it behaves weirdly with addition and mutiplication (e.g. `sys.float_info.max * 2 = inf`)

So I would need a infinite inf such that `inf * 0 = 0`, `inf + x = inf` (for `x` finite), and `inf * k = +/- inf` (when `k` is not zero)

Do you know such object, or how I could declare it in python ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Note that `float('inf') * 0` produces a distinct NaN, so you may want to simply filter your array afterwards, replacing `float('inf') * 0` with 0.

Comment: (Compare `struct.pack("d", float('nan'))` and `struct.pack("d", float('inf') * 0)`.)

Comment: (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infinity-multiplied-by-zero-not-an-easy-zero-answer) for a discussion about what infinity times 0 means, or doesn't mean.)

Comment: Also check out np.nan_to_num. It replace inf with large finite numbers, which will get you what you want with inf * 0. You can investigate the rest of the behavior if the post this was marked as a duplicate of or chepner's answer doesn't do it.